# Phonegap build apk fails with FontFamilyFont errors

Tags: android, cordova, build, apk, phonegap

I'm using https://build.phonegap.com to build my apk and ipa file.

I create the zip package and update it, then I download apk/ipa.

From today I have a trouble: the apk file isn't compiled, I can see errors in the log (while the ipa is generated).

Note I didin't change anything on Android settings, I think there is an Android update causing this.

The Phonegap log says (this is only the trailer):

> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 4.069 secs
>
> Error: /gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font
>
> ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontStyle
>
> ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings
>
> ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute
>   android:fontWeight ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont,
>   unable to find attribute android:ttcIndex
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

I work with DevExtreme, a Phonegap based platform, so the working solutions for pure Phonegap should be ok for my project too.

My config.xml is

```
<widget id="com.devexpress.apptemplate" version="1.0" versionCode="1">
  <name>ApplicationTemplate</name>
  <description>Template</description>
  <author email="info@info.com" href="http://www.info.com/">Info</author>
  <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />
  <icon src="icon/ios/icon.png" width="1024" height="1024" />
  <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
  <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
  </feature>
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26" />
  <platform name="android">
    <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
  </platform>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="2.4.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" onload="true" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix" />
  <!--<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" onload="true" />-->
  <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="2.0.0" />
  <plugin spec="https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/BarcodeScanner.git" source="git">
    <param name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To scan barcodes." />
  </plugin>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^2.4.1" source="npm">
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="This app requires access to take picture and send them, if needed." />
    <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="This app requires access to the photo library to send them, if needed." />
  </plugin>
  <access origin="*" />
  <!--<engines>
    <engine name="android" spec="^6.3.0" />
  </engines>-->
</widget>
```

Comment: I noticed, reading from the phonegap forum, this is a common issue starting from today... what the hell are doing in phonegap?

Comment: You need to update your compile SDK to the android P preview. You can download it in the SDK manager and then you need to update the compile SDK your build.gradle file to android P preview. You're getting these errors because one of the libraries you're using is referencing resources that were added only in P API.

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska Working with Phonegap, I'm not able (or, I don't know how) to update the SDK, I never used the SDK manager too... can you give me an hint? I  think I have to edit my config.xml, but I don't know how

Comment: @downvoter at least, explain why...

Comment: sorry, no idea how to set it in the phonegap. In Android Studio you can edit your build.gradle files.. Just a quick google for Phonegap gives me an idea to try adding this to your config.xml "<platform name="android"><preference name="android-compileSdkVersion" value="android-P" /></platform>". You can also use the SDK manager to download the "android P preview" SDK first.

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska excuse me the dumb question, what is "android P preview" ?

Comment: Each API (15, 19, 22, 27 etc) corresponds to a latter/dessert name (Ice Cream Sandwich, KitKat, Lollipop, Oreo etc). "android P preview" is a preview for the yet unreleased android P (we don't know the dessert name yet) which is API 28. When it gets release you will be able to say 28 or P, for now it's a preview so it's called "android P preview". If you use the SDK manager it will be the top suggestion.

Comment: Here's a table with the API level and name for each version (no P since it hasn't been released yet): https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska thanks for the support. I found a solution, you can read it below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the magic trick to solve this.

I added this in my config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release">
     <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="26.0.0"/>
</plugin>
```

And changed targetSdkVersion to 26:

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26"/>
```

Comment: This way you're forcing the support library to use version 26.0.0. It might conflict if your other libraries were built for newer APIs. I'm glad it works for you, but please keep this in mind. :) Soon API 28 will be released and then you can update both the support lib version and target sdk version to 28.